# Ciclo de um mês ao outro - PHP

Tags: php, data

Desenvolvi a ideia abaixo, buscando ter os períodos de 21 a 20 de cada mês (21/08/2021 a 20/09/2021), porém, se a data atual for menor do que 20, precisa voltar um mês atrás, então seria 21/07/2021 a 20/08/2021. Atualmente, meu resultado é 21/08 a 20/09. Onde estou errando?

```
public function get_ciclo_atual($hoje, $dia_inicial=21, $dia_final=20){
    $ciclo = array();
    $hoje = date("Y-m-d");
    if(date("d", strtotime($hoje)) >= $dia_inicial){
        $ciclo[0] = date("Y", strtotime($hoje))."-".date("m", strtotime($hoje))."-".$dia_inicial;
        $ciclo[1] = date("Y", strtotime($hoje))."-".date("m", strtotime($hoje." +1 month"))."-".$dia_final;
    }else{
        $ciclo[0] = date("Y", strtotime($hoje))."-".date("m", strtotime($hoje." -1 month"))."-".$dia_inicial;
        $ciclo[1] = date("Y", strtotime($hoje))."-".date("m", strtotime($ciclo[0]." +1 month"))."-".$dia_final;     
    }

    return $ciclo;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O mês atual é setembro (`9`), então se quer a data inicial no mês 7 e a data final no mês 8, você precisa subtrair 2 meses para obter a inicial e 1 mês para a final:

```php
function get_ciclo_atual($dia_inicial=21, $dia_final=20) {
    $ciclo = array();
    $hoje = time(); // data atual
    // se dia atual é maior ou igual ao início, data inicial está 1 mês antes e data final está no mês atual
    if (date("d", $hoje) >= $dia_inicial) {
        $ciclo[0] = date("Y-m-$dia_inicial", strtotime("-1 month", $hoje));
        $ciclo[1] = date("Y-m-$dia_final", $hoje);
    } else { // senão, data inicial está 2 meses antes, e data final está 1 mês antes
        $ciclo[0] = date("Y-m-$dia_inicial", strtotime("-2 month", $hoje));
        $ciclo[1] = date("Y-m-$dia_final", strtotime("-1 month", $hoje));
    }

    return $ciclo;
}
```

Eu também removi o parâmetro `$hoje` da função, pois uma das primeiras coisas que você faz é sobrescrevê-lo (ao fazer `$hoje = ...`). Ou seja, este parâmetro era inútil. Ou você recebe `$hoje` como parâmetro e usa o valor que foi passado, ou você remove o parâmetro e usa sempre a data atual.

Por exemplo, se a ideia é receber como parâmetro, aí seria:

```
function get_ciclo_atual($hoje, $dia_inicial=21, $dia_final=20) {
    // NÃO setar $hoje = ...., apenas use o valor de $hoje que foi passado
    // todo o resto é igual
}
```

Enfim, decida se vai receber a data `$hoje` como parâmetro ou se vai sempre pegar a data atual dentro da própria função.

---

Outra opção é usar [`mktime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) para construir as datas, e formatá-las somente ao final, quando for montar o array:

```php
function get_ciclo_atual($dia_inicial=21, $dia_final=20) {
    $hoje = time(); // data atual
    $mes = date('m', $hoje) - 1; // começa no mês anterior
    $ano = date('Y', $hoje); // ano atual
    if (date("d", $hoje) < $dia_inicial) {
        $mes--; // // nesse caso, volta mais um mês
    }
    return array(
        date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes, $dia_inicial, $ano)),
        date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, $mes + 1, $dia_final, $ano))
    );
}
```

`mktime` já cuida dos casos em que o mês é menor que 1 (por exemplo, se o mês atual for 1 e tiver que subtrair 2, ele já trata `-1` como novembro do ano anterior, se o mês for dezembro, ao somar 1 ele já ajusta para janeiro do ano seguinte, etc).

Comment: Perfeito. Obrigado por sua resposta. E se for de um ano para o outro? exemplo: 21/12/2021 a 20/01/2021, dessa forma iria funcionar da mesma maneira?

Comment: @Sr.AndréBaill Não seria de 21/12/2021 a 20/01/202**2**? Enfim, se você somar um mês ou 1 ano (ou qualquer outra unidade de tempo) a `mktime` ou `strtotime`, eles fazem os ajustes necessários

Comment: Perdão, 2022 mesmo.

Comment: Mas por exemplo, chegou dezembro, tenho que alterar manualmente, isso?

Comment: @Sr.AndréBaill Não precisa alterar nada, `mktime` e `strtotime` já ajustam automaticamente se mudar o ano: https://ideone.com/32YXyq

Comment: Como eu conseguiria fazer um loop entre os meses do ano? Exemplo: no mesmo ciclo do mês 10/2021 a 09/2022, (seria então ciclo atual + 11 ciclos) conseguiria me ajudar?

Comment: @Sr.AndréBaill Se eu entendi direito, é só mudar a função pra receber a data como parâmetro (em vez de sempre usar a data atual). Seria algo assim: https://ideone.com/7Ysvid - Mas **caso não seja isso**, aí sugiro que faça outra pergunta explicando melhor a regra...

Comment: Perfeito, é isso. Eu consigo retornar todo resultado em apenas um array, com data_inicio e data_fim?

Comment: @Sr.AndréBaill Cada chamada de `get_ciclo` retorna um novo array com a data de início e fim daquele ciclo. O que fazer com esses arrays (se vai juntar todos em um só, ou manter cada um separado), aí é com vc :-)

Comment: Sim, a ideia é juntar todos em um só, pois vou exibi-los em um select. :)

Comment: @Sr.AndréBaill Ué, então é só criar um array (`$todos = []`) e no `while` vc adiciona os ciclos nele: `$todos[] = get_ciclo(...)`

Comment: Compreendi, obrigado pelas dicas.

Comment: Infelizmente eu não consegui encaixar a ideia do ciclo para um ano. Vi que você me deu as dicas em geral, mas não consegui decifrar. Consegue me ajudar?

Comment: @Sr.AndréBaill Nesse caso eu acho melhor fazer outra pergunta dando todos os detalhes do que vc quer e o que está dando errado. É melhor porque perguntas novas ficam na página principal e mais gente vai ver (aqui só eu estou vendo, provavelmente), além de ter mais espaço pra explicar o problema em detalhes